# How do I access constants and notations from structures in MMT?

Tags: dependent-type, theorem-proving, formal-methods, mmt

Given the following theories, which formalize meaningless stuff for the purpose of a small MWE,

```
theory Meta : http://cds.omdoc.org/urtheories?LF =
  ℕ: type ❙
  prop: type ❙
  or: prop ⟶ prop ⟶ prop ❘ # 1 ∨ 2 ❙
❚

theory S : ?Meta =
  c: ℕ ⟶ ℕ ⟶ prop ❘ # 1 + 2 ❙
  d: ℕ ⟶ ℕ ⟶ ℕ ⟶ prop ❘ # 1 |- 2 ∶ 3 ❙
❚
```

how do I access the contents from `S` when having declared two `S`-structures as below?

```
theory T : ?Meta =
  structure s1 : ?S = ❚
  structure s2 : ?S = ❚

  n: ℕ ❙

  // How do I access constants c, d and their notations from s1, s2?
❚
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Constants are available via `<structure name>/<constant name>`

```
theory T : ?Meta =
  structure s1 : ?S = ❚
  structure s2 : ?S = ❚

  n: ℕ ❙

  c_usage1 = s1/c n n ❙
  c_usage2 = s2/c n n ❙
  c_usage_combined = (s1/c n n) ∨ (s2/c n n) ❙

  d_usage1 = s1/d n n ❙
  d_usage2 = s2/d n n ❙
  d_usage_combined = (s1/d n n) ∨ (s2/d n n ) ❙
❚
```

#### Notations get `<structure name>/` prepended to their *first* presentation marker

For instance, the notation defined as `# 1 + 2` has only the single [presentation marker](https://uniformal.github.io/apidoc/info/kwarc/mmt/api/notations/TextNotation.html#presentationMarkers:List%5Binfo.kwarc.mmt.api.notations.Marker%5D) `+`, thus is accessed via `... <structure name>/+ ...`.
On the other hand, a notation defined as `# 1 |- 2 ∶ 3` has two presentation markers: `|-` and `∶`. It is accessed via `... <structure name>/|- ... ∶ ...`:

```
theory T : ?Meta =
  structure s1 : ?S = ❚
  structure s2 : ?S = ❚

  n: ℕ ❙

  c_usage1 = n s1/+ n ❙
  c_usage2 = n s2/+ n ❙
  c_usage_combined = (n s1/+ n) ∨ (n s2/+ n) ❙

  d_usage1 = n s1/|- n ∶ n ❙
  d_usage2 = n s2/|- n ∶ n ❙
  d_usage_combined = (n s1/|- n ∶ n) ∨ (n s2/|- n ∶ n) ❙
❚
```